# Where or how does one come by phrases like “I’m disinclined to acquiesce to your request”?

Tags: phrase-requests

> I’m disinclined to acquiesce to your request. Means “no”.

How does one find more phrases like that? What are such type of phrases called?

Comment: You're looking for *pleonasms". To broaden your search, look up synonyms of "pleonastic" in a thesaurus.

Comment: Apparently you ask a pirate.

Comment: It's called English.

Comment: You learn a lot of words.  Such phrases are basically just "extraordinarily wordy".  It's a skill many lawyers, politicians, preachers, and used car salesmen cultivate.

Comment: Ah ye of little learning and faith. You need to get youse some book learning.

Comment: These are called 'convoluted phrases' or, similarly, 'purple prose'.  Read the Bronte sisters for more.

Comment: Carefully study Sir Humphrey in _Yes Minister_ and _Yes, Prime Minister_.

Comment: But it  isn't convoluted at all. "I'm likely to say no to your request."  It is an exaggeration for comical effect, yes, but it's aping the actual speech of the time. And to answer the OP's question: Go read some Restoration Comedy. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the title question is requesting resources and the request for a name is a duplicate (look up 'purple prose').

Comment: To me, this seems completely appropriate re ELU, though the OP should have posted the background ab initio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to look this one up myself. Pleonasms seem to be different from the questioned meaning, being another word for redundant. The questioned phrase appears to be called a "tumid euphemism" with tumid meaning "swollen" which would indicate wordiness.

Comment: but the OP asks:  where does one find more like the example?

Comment: It is not a pleonasm at all. If you say to someone: I'm probably going to say no, is that pleonastic?

Comment: A Google search for "tumid euphemism" (in quotes) returns _only_ this ELU question. Would you mind citing your source(s)?

Answer (score 1):

**You have to hand it to the scriptwriters. They studied their Restoration Comedy**.

Restoration Comedy came after the restoration of British monarchy in 1660, that roughly coincided with the Golden Age of Piracy.

[Golden Age of Piracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Age_of_Piracy)

In  regular English that is: "I'm probably going to say no." Or: "I'm likely to say no". It isn't really a pleonasm.

It's comical as it's meant to sound like U English. There would be no Restoration Comedy without that manner of speech, much given to exaggeration of the social mores it was making fun of.

The sentence is from Pirates of the Caribbean: [Curse of the Black Pearl](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0325980/quotes)

The two most famous playrights were William Wycherley (The Country Wife and The Plain Dealer) and William Congreve (The Way of the World and Love for Love [the most well-known plays), in the first and second waves of Restoration Comedy, respectively.

Jack Sparrow's speech patterns in these movies are very exaggerated and he tries to sound like an upper class speaker. Indeed, many pirates were in fact upper class. And this "drawing room" type of speech would be typical of them. And I can't be bothered to do more research on whether he was or not. Suffice it to say, he was merely using speech typical of the age.

Comment: It is too bad about the downvote. Sour grapes?

Comment: FYI: Jack Sparrow didn't say the line in question. It was Captain Barbossa, and then later Elizabeth Swan delivers the line back to him by proxy. (See http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Pirates-of-the-Caribbean.html)

Comment: Yes, yes, I mis-attributed but my premise remains. Modern scriptwriters can only learn that speech by reading Restoration Comedy. Where that type of speech  is everywhere.